# C# - Using ICollection<T> in generic property instead of Collection<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

`Collection<T>` is a Class, `ICollection<T>` is an interface.
In the MVC tutorial I find this

```
public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

But `ICollection` is an interface, I don't understand why it's like that. The correct way to implement a generic property is this one:

```
public MyProp<int> SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

So, by the example, it should be something like

```
public Collection<int> SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

`ICollection` is an interface so its implementation should be:

```
public class ClassName : ICollection<T>
```

I searched for similar questions but I only found an example on how to create a generic property

Comment: Read up on polymorphism

Comment: Since in object oriented design you want to depend on abstractions instead of implementations, you should never have a member of your own implementations with the concrete type List/List. http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/

Comment: Why do you think that a property can't have an interface as the type, and needs to have a concrete class as it's type?

Answer (score 1):

This approach perfectly makes sense because of the fact that classes were designed to encapsulate the underlying implementation of themselves. Furthermore, Interfaces were designed to standardize this approach. To understand it better, think about the `IEnumarable<T>` interface. If you implement this interface on any of your class design, your class automatically becomes enumerable (which means that it can be used with foreach).

In your case, it returns `ICollection<T>` bacause they want you to use the standardized interface methods.

If you write the following code

```
var enrollment = myObj.Enrollments
```

the enrollment variable will automatically be treated as the following

```
ICollection<Enrollment> enrollment = myObj.Enrollments
```

This approach pushes you to write a modular code with a better design since you end up using the standardized interface calls.

As in every situation, you sometimes need to create exceptions. If anything like that comes up, you can basically use the type that you want to cast to as the following.

```
Collection<Enrollment> enrollment = myObj.Enrollments
```

With this approach, you can reach all the public methods coming from the `Collection<T>` class

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly normal for a class that implements a generic interface to be generic itself. For example, `List<T>` implements `IList<T>`.

Or, for example,

```
public interface IDoesSomethingWith<T>
{
    void DoSomethingWith(T theThing);
}

public class DoesSomethingWith<T> : IDoesSomethingWith<T>
{
    public void DoSomethingWith(T theThing)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Generic type arguments can be declared at either the class level *or* the method level. For example, you can do this:

```
public class DoesSomethingWith<T> : IDoesSomethingWith<T>
{
    public void DoSomethingWith(T theThing)
    {
        // uses generic type of class
    }

    public void DoSomethingWith<TAnotherThing>(TAnotherThing anotherThing)
    {
        // uses generic type of method
    }

    public void DoSomethingWith<TAnotherThing>(T thing, TAnotherThing anotherThing)
    {
        // uses generic type of class and method
    }
}
```

An implementation of a generic interface (or a class that inherits from a generic class) *can* specify a concrete type rather than being generic itself.

In this example the interface is generic, but the class that implements it is not.

```
public interface IDoesSomethingWith<T>
{
    void DoSomethingWith(T theThing);
}

public class DoesSomethingWithInt : IDoesSomethingWith<int>
{
    public void DoSomethingWith(int theThing)
    {

    }
}
```